# VoiP to connections?

Tags: voip, telephony

I have been recently playing with AsterixNow and got a nice network set-up with trunks and sips.
Outgoing calls go to a VoIP provider that charge me say 2pence per minute for local mobile.
I have been looking and trying to research how VoIP providers connect to the rest of the worlds networks, eg in UK British Telecom.I read up that they use MDE's that connect in tandem to other networks.. fair enough.. How does VoIP providers connect to BT

As in UK Calling BT landlines is free and many EU based VoIP providers offer UK landlines free.. but also offer free landlines calls to tens of other countries(in which the biggest telecom don't offer free land line calls to any customer)

If I would like to offer my own VoIP service how would I plug directly into "a network"?

I know allot of places offer reseller options and affiliate. but I am not interested in that.

Does anybody know or have experience with this sort of thing?

Comment: I am not very familiar with telecommunications structures outside the US, though I'd imagine it is fairly similar. You can see my answer here for some details about how VoIP works from a provider's perspective: http://superuser.com/questions/325891/what-are-the-internal-workings-of-google-voice/325926#325926

Comment: Yea I think I understand the routing mechanisms but how do i physically connect to my local telecoms?besides the obvios phone line at my office- i mean like get 50 numbers and access to the raw networks

Comment: Most VoIP providers don't do that part, it is handled by the gateway device of their vendor - they're the ones that interface with the PSTN lines. The VoIP providers simply have a set of IP's that they route to depending on the end-point for the number. Now if you aren't going to do enterprise sip to pstn trunking, say just a few numbers, you can get more affordable solutions by using Asterisk (enterprise pstn gateways are well into the $10k mark). Depending on how everything is setup there, you may need to rent Colo space at the Central Office as well.

Comment: Problem with using sip-to-pstn is that one pstn line is £10 per month no inclusive calls. and call charges are more than VoIP. I want to avoid that. So basically to bypass VoIP companies I need to lease some group of SIPs? using some hectic equipment and big costs.

Comment: a PSTN gateway doesn't mean getting PSTN lines at a monthly rate, it is what does the digital to analog conversion and physically interfaces with the phone company's PSTN network. This is typically done at the CO, or further up the chain (with a vendor, who actually routes the PSTN networks of multiple phone companies - at least here in the US, again, not completely sure of how it is with BT).

Comment: Oh right i get it now.I thought of a PSTN Gateway as one of those wher i plug my PSTN into the gatway and allow it to have acces from asterix to my landlines.. you mentioned it using VoiP trunks to PSTN. I would like to know how to find a Vendro who routes the PSTN networks basically. Been searching a few days cant really get anything concrete.

Comment: Well, Level 3 is a huge one, 360 Networks and Global Crossing are also pretty big. As far as I know, they all have fairly large international presences. Those 3 handle much of the backbone for companies like AT&T, Verizon, Megapath, Covad, etc. They not only supply the IP addresses they use, they also supply the phone numbers.

Comment: Ya- That last comment sounds like the answer i was looking for :) (write an answer)  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UK getting ISDN lines is the best way to plug into the local telepgony network.

BT offers ISDN 20/50/100/+ - For very good rental rates.

I am sure there are other providers..

I did find a SIP provider that provides unlimited Channels and and 3 Tier Quality trunks with highly competitive prices. Solves all the problems from my end in using land lines.